# Validate acceptance of terms: validate_acceptance_of succeeds if terms_accepted is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

When creating a user, I'm checking if the terms of usage were accepted like so:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_acceptance_of :terms, :message => :terms_not_accepted, :on => :create
  attr_accessible :terms, :on => :create # required because I completely disable mass-assignment in an initializer
end
```

I have the following fields in my form view:

```
<label class="checkbox"><%= f.check_box :terms %><span><%=t "users.form.label.terms" %></span></label>
```

So far, everything works as expected. If the user does not accept the terms, there will be an error message. **However, if I just remove the checkbox (and corresponding hidden field generated by the view helper) from the HTML page using e.g. Chrome developer tools, the user will be created!**

I can reproduce this in the console:

```
irb(main):001:0> u = User.new # => #<User ...>
irb(main):002:0> u.terms # => nil
irb(main):003:0> u.save! # => other validations fail, but terms check succeeds!
irb(main):004:0> u.terms = false # => false
irb(main):005:0> u.save! # => terms validation fails as expected
```

One more info: `validates :terms, :acceptance => true` yields the same result

I know that I can initialize the terms attribute with `false` in an `after_initialize` callback, but I do not want to do that since the validator should be able to handle the `nil` case. So **is this a bug in rails or am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd like to make sure that the user accepts terms, then you can set allow_nil to false

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000082

```
:allow_nil - Skip validation if attribute is nil (default is true).
```

So change to

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms, :on => :create, :allow_nil => false, :message => :terms_not_accepted,
```

Comment: Sure! it's so that you could still create a User outside of the user interface, but if you were in the interface it would require the terms acceptance.

Comment: Yes, I understand the purpose of this default setting; but find it's a bit unfortunate that you can just remove the checkbox flags from the HTML or issue a CURL POST to the user creation without the need to accept the terms. I do not think it's a searious issue, but can imagine that ~95% of the rails websites using this implementation have the same problem.

Comment: I agree with blackbird07. allow_nil should default to false on :acceptance validator. As far as console/test are considered: use factory gems for object creation (ie. fabrication or factory_girl). Without it object creationg is unconvenient event without additional checkboxy field.

Comment: What it makes it even stranger is that for example `LengthValidator` acts as it have `allow_nil: false` by default..